# Scanning Android MediaStore for image folders

Tags: android, image, image-gallery, mediastore

I need to scan the Android media store for image folder paths which I pass to another activity which displays images from the selected folder. My current code which does the job, but crashes on certain image paths and extensions (e.g. `some image &%^$%*5.png`, and `some image.bin`):

```
final String[] columns = {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
};
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;

Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
        null, orderBy);

mExternalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

mCount = cursor.getCount();
// mAbsolutePath is the absolute path (e.g. //emulated/0/folder/picture.png)
mAbsolutePath = new String[mCount];
mDisplayName = new String[mCount];
// mFolderIntentPath is what will eventually become the folder path (e.g. //emulated/0/folder/)
mFolderIntentPath = new String[mCount];
mBucket = new String[mCount];

for (int i = 0; i < this.mCount; i++) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int absolutePathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    int displayNameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int bucketColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

    mAbsolutePath[i]= cursor.getString(absolutePathColumnIndex);
    mDisplayName[i] = cursor.getString(displayNameColumnIndex);
    mBucket[i] = cursor.getString(bucketColumnIndex);
    mFolderIntentPath[i] = mAbsolutePath[i].substring(0, mAbsolutePath[i].length() - mDisplayName[i].length());
}
```

Is there a better way of getting the image folder paths?

EDIT: Here is the logcat:

```
05-05 04:11:36.200  13580-13580/com.sinisa.eyesonly E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=64; regionStart=20; regionLength=-1
            at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
            at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
            at com.sinisa.eyesonly.gui.fragment.FragmentGallery.scanMediaStoreFolders(FragmentGallery.java:113)
            at com.sinisa.eyesonly.gui.fragment.FragmentGallery.onCreateView(FragmentGallery.java:75)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:474)
            at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 04:11:36.216      387-669/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.sinisa.eyesonly/.gui.MainActivity
```

When i id call `Log.d` on `mDistinct` and `mAbsolutePath` like this:

```
            mAbsolutePath[i]= cursor.getString(absolutePathColumnIndex);
            Log.d("bitmap","abs" + mAbsolutePath[i]);
            mDisplayName[i] = cursor.getString(displayNameColumnIndex);
            Log.d("bitmap","dis" + mDisplayName[i]);
```

i get:

```
05-05 04:11:36.184  13580-13580/com.sinisa.eyesonly D/bitmap﹕ abs/storage/emulated/0/Snapchat/Snapchat-20140425090242.jpg
05-05 04:11:36.184  13580-13580/com.sinisa.eyesonly D/bitmap﹕ disSnapchat-20140425090242.jpg
05-05 04:11:36.184  13580-13580/com.sinisa.eyesonly D/bitmap﹕ abs/storage/emulated/0/Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png
05-05 04:11:36.184  13580-13580/com.sinisa.eyesonly D/bitmap﹕ disUniversal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png
```

Comment: You say that this code crashes on certain image paths. Could you edit your question to include the exception you're getting and the line that's triggering the exception?

Comment: I updated the answer per your request. If anything else is needed ill be glad to provide.

Comment: So according to the exception you're getting, `mDisplayName[i].length() > mAbsolutePath[i].length()`.

Comment: Yes, and this happened to me only with the file path like the above "Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png" and a few times with .bin files (downloaded pictures from gmail and scanned by mediastore i guess).

Comment: One further suggestion: instead of walls of text, you could've cut it down to "line `foo = bar` throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, but how is that possible?"  Being minimal helps both for communication and debugging.

Comment: I know, but I'm new to both SO and programming, so it's still an abstract task for me to strip the question down to bare essentials and be sure that it would be enough for someone experienced to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
mFolderIntentPath[i] = mAbsolutePath[i].substring(0, mAbsolutePath[i].length() - mDisplayName[i].length());
```

According to the exception you're getting, `mDisplayName[i].length() > mAbsolutePath[i].length()`.  I'm guessing that this is because the display name is not *always* the name of the file.  If you want to strip off the base name to get just the directory name, you might want to try to get the index at which to cut it off in a different way, say like

```
mFolderIntentPath[i] = mAbsolutePath[i].substring(0, mAbsolutePath[i].lastIndexOf('/'));
```